# How to draw an image to canvas with a certain color set to alpha?

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite, alpha, sprite-sheet

If I have a spritesheet, and I'm using [ctx.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) (the variant with 8 args) to slice sprites from the sheet and draw them to a canvas, how can I tell javascript to ignore certain colors? For example, when slicing from [this](https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/preview_177.png), the blue color wouldn't be rendered. I did some searching but couldn't find anyone else asking this question.

Comment: Why are you using the preview png? Just get the actual one and it's semitransparent. Here, click the red download button: https://kenney.nl/assets/boardgame-pack

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have just posted the one I was using. [The background is white.](https://i.imgur.com/Hw8wfdU.png)

Comment: I'd probably open the spritesheet up in paint.net or something and make the background transparent. Otherwise you're most likely going to have to manually edit the imageData bit by bit to apply whatever transparency logic you want to use.